# Changing wordpress thems's CSS with media queries

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, media-queries

I am looking to improve the style of a Wordpress site.
I have a div with the group-input class which has this style:

```
.group-input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: right;
 }
```

I would like that below 572 px of screen we switch to float : left so I wrote this below the previous code, in my theme's CSS file, like this:

```
 .group-input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: right;
 }

@media (max-width: 572px) {
    .group-input {
        float: left !important;
    }
}
```

On the other hand it does not work, the new style does not apply to my div.
suddenly I don't know how to do it. Do you have an idea, a lead to advise me?
I want some explanations, something simple for you is not necessarily obvious to me suddenly I need to understand. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: This is probably not the problem, but if you really need !important (and you may not) it should go before the semi colon. If that doesn’t cure things please tell us exactly which file you have added this css to, is it a child theme?

Comment: I add the !important as a test to "see" if that worked... but it doesn't ! Thanks for answering me.
I add the css to style.css file. I thought it was the best place...
in the console  (F12) when I change the float right to left, the effect I'm looking for works fine... that's why I wanted to modify it on the style.css

Answer (score 0):

In general, that should overwrite the css rule you are trying to do, but it's probably another css rule that more specifically targets that element. A few reasons it may not be overwriting is because:

- another css rule is more specific than yours
- it's in a breakpoint more specific than yours
- it uses !important

A combo of all of those will require you to be even more specific in targeting the element.

If you find you are unable to overwrite a rule, try and be more specific in your targeting of the element by targeting it's grandparent/parent and working down the html tree. If you notice that that isn't working either, then try using !important.

Check the html structure around it try that. Sometimes even `body .group-input` might be specific enough, but the closer you specify to the element, the better off you will be.

Comment: thanks for helping, I'm searching for that, thank you for your clear explanations and taking the time to help me. :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck.